# insert input type column in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I'm having a problem in bootstrap table, I have a bootstrap table populated by a data from a database by using `JQuery AJAX`, what I want to do is insert/add `<input type="text"/>` on last column on every record.

**My Jquery Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        var baseurl = "<?php print site_url('/quotes/get'); ?>";                  

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: baseurl,
                data: { analid: 1 },
                dataType: 'json'
            })
                .done(function( msg ) {

                console.log(msg);

                $('#qtable').bootstrapTable({
                    data: msg
                });

            });

    });
</script>
```

the script above is working displaying the data from database, then I found this reference([*LINK HERE*](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?kePUDn73)), on the bottom part of that web is where I saw some method of `bootstraptable` like adding static column.

**Updated Code Jquery Script:**

```
 $(function() {
    var baseurl = "<?php print site_url('index.php/quotes/get'); ?>";
    $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: baseurl,
            data: {
                analid: 1
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(msg) {

            console.log(msg);

            $('#qtable').bootstrapTable({
                data: msg,
                columns: [{ //<--- here is where I lost.. I don't know what to do here or what should I add..
                    field: 'operate',
                    title: 'Item Operate',
                    align: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle',
                    clickToSelect: false,
                    formatter: operateFormatter,
                    events: operateEvents
                }]

            });

        });
});
```

Any alternative and optimized way solutions is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use column option `formatter`  . see example [HERE](http://www.redexperu.com/assets/js/bootstrap-table-master/docs/examples.html#format-table)

```
formatter : function(value,row,index) {
   return '<input name="elementname"  value="'+value+'"/>';
   //return '<input name="elementname"  value="'+row.id+'"/>';     here id is your field name
 }
```

The cell formatter function, take three parameters:

1. value: the field value.
2. row: the row record data.
3. index: the row index.

in this case your code will be as below.(assume that 'operate' is your last column name )

```
$('#qtable').bootstrapTable({
            data: msg,
            columns: [{ //<--- here is where I lost.. I don't know what to do here or what should I add..
                field: 'operate',
                title: 'Item Operate',
                align: 'center',
                valign: 'middle',
                clickToSelect: false,
                formatter : function(value,row,index) {
                   return '<input name="elementname"  value="'+value+'"/>';
                   //return '<input name="elementname"  value="'+row.id+'"/>';     here id is your field name 
                }  
            }]

        });
```

Comment: it totally works.. but it display on the first column.. I want it to display on last column(though I add `data-formatter ="operate"`).

Comment: What is your last field name in json array??

Comment: ahh. so it must be based on the `json array`.. sorry my bad.. but what I actually mean is the input text element must be dynamically added when data is loaded. But it is possible to add dynamic input text element on bootstrap-table?

Comment: Basically when you load json array ..you know which is last field load to table .

Comment: Here you want to add input after data load to table ??

Comment: how can I put the `ID Column` data (from database data also included in returned json) to assign in dynamically added `<input type=text id=id(from db)/>`, using **bootstrapTable** function see sample image: [IMAGE HERE](http://s21.postimg.org/3mprxyemf/smaple.png)

Comment: @Waelhi let me check how to pass other object value here

Comment: i think you need to try like  msg[index].id inside formatter function ? check my updated answer .. may be this will work

Comment: no. it didn't work. it display `Loading, please wait...` and I wait for about 5mins but it didn't show it return empty table.

Comment: @Waelhi can you please check what is error in console ?

Comment: @Waelhi can you post your json object or give me key for your id column in josn

Comment: @Waelhi check my updated answer . use like row.id  . here id is your id field key name

Comment: @Waelhi http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1286/  check this example i have update value for first row name with Forks value .

Comment: yes it works! thanks! but I do have another problem. Can you please check this out: [SO LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651581/get-element-value-from-dynamically-added-element-inside-bootstrap-table)

Comment: @Waelhi i have added my answer to your question .check .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return / render column at known position, simply use the following function block

```
formatter : function(value,row,index) {
   return '<input name="elementname"  value="'+value+'"/>';
 }
```

If you want to exclude / skip some columns or want to render particular column (add empty curly braces pairs {},{},{}, like this according to how much column you have to shift)
for example,

```
columns: [ {},{},{},  

           {
             field: 'operate',
             title: 'Item Operate',
             align: 'center',
             valign: 'middle',
             clickToSelect: false,
             formatter : function(value,row,index) {
               return '<input name="elementname"  value="'+value+'"/>';
             }
           }
         ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this library, but I looked at the docs and this is what I think you need.  formatter can just be a anonymous function like this:

```
formatter : function(value) {
    //value contains the current value in the cell.  whatever you return will be the new value of the cell.
       return '<input name="myinput" />';
}
```