# get element value from dynamically added element inside bootstrap-table

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap-table and populated/filled data via database using JQuery.I added a column(last column) element type(input type='text') dynamically. My problem is, how can I get the data I input on dynamically added input type(text).

My reference for my Bootstrap-table: [LINK HERE!](http://www.redexperu.com/assets/js/bootstrap-table-master/docs/examples.html#via-javascript-table)

**Jquery Sample Code:**(I tried this, but it gives me `NULL`)

```
$('#accordion-table').on('blur','.input-sm',function() {         
    var txt = $(this).text();        
    alert(txt);             
});
```

And also how to get the selected value on `OPTION element` and it is dynamic element also.

*see sample image below:*

[image]

Both elements are dynamically added.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Link is not available..share a JS fiddle link..

Comment: Assign an `ID` to the column that you add dynamically. Then get the value from that column using this `var value = $(#dynamicColumnID).val();`

Comment: Strange but I am able to open the link

Comment: http://www.redexperu.com/assets/js/bootstrap-table-master/docs/examples.html#via-javascript-table

Comment: @Ankit The value is to be retrieved on blur. You won't be able to get the value because new elements will not be bound to blur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use below code to get value from input text box  .  check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/e3nk137y/1295/)

use `.val()` instead of `.text()`

to attach event to dynamically created element use [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

```
$(document).on('blur','.input-sm',function() {         
  var txt = $(this).val();        
  alert(txt);             
});
```

Comment: woow.. it works! thanks! but how about the select option element how can I get the default/selected value? heres my sample code: [IMAGE LINK](http://s10.postimg.org/4ba0lw5cp/select_option.png)

Comment: Remove closest and use parent

Comment: it returns `undefined`.

Comment: OK I will check and let you know when I reach work place . its morning 8 am here :)

Comment: use this code .  `var txt = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5) select').val(); `

provide proper index of td . index is start with 0 not from 1. and add `select` as you want to get select box value not td :)

check this http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1307/